# How to Prevent jQuery Back to Top Button from Requiring Double Tap on Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I'm using a Back to Top Button that appears when the user scrolls 300px down the page on a WordPress site I'm developing, and on my phone, it's making me double tap to get the scroll to work. I'm wondering if there's a way to adjust this so the button fires on the first tap.

Here's the test site URL: http://tippingpointphoto.flywheelsites.com/

Here's the code I'm using:

HTML

```
<a href="#" class="topbutton">Back to Top</a>
```

CSS

```
.topbutton {
font-family:$noto-sans;
font-size:14px;
text-align:center;
color:$white;
height:65px;
width:75px;
padding:.5em;
position:fixed;
right:5px;
bottom:5px;
z-index:1;
text-decoration:none;
background:$button-gray;
display:none;

&:hover{
  background:$blue;
  color: $white;
}
}
```

jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var offset = 300;
    var speed = 250;
    var duration = 500;
     $(window).scroll(function(){
            if ($(this).scrollTop() < offset) {
           $('.topbutton') .fadeOut(duration);
            } else {
           $('.topbutton') .fadeIn(duration);
            }
        });
  $('.topbutton').on('click', function(){
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0}, speed);
    return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across a similar problem of trying to replicate hover actions on mobile with a single tap. Try adding one of these lines (or both) to your `.ready` function:

```
$('body').bind('touchstart', function() {});
// and/or
document.addEventListener("touchstart", function(){}, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Where would I put these lines within my current jQuery code?

Comment: Anywhere within your `jQuery(document).ready(function($){});` :) They can just be dropped right in to test if they work.